# Im new to python and having an issue with my list being out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so im getting a list index out of range here:

`for i in range(len(empNr)):`

`print(empNr[i], rate[i], hrs[i], wkPay[i])`

and I haven't really figured lists out, so I may just be confused and am unable to understand why i would be out of range. here the rest of the code below. thanks!

```
SENTINEL = 0
wkTotal = payHigh = wkPay = empHigh = 0 

empNr = []
rate = []
hrs = []
wkPay = []

i = 0
empNr.append(input("Input first employee number: "))
#iteration if 0 is entered it should stop
while (empNr[i] != str(SENTINEL)):
    rate.append(int(input("Input rate: ")))
    hrs.append(int(input("Input hours: ")))
    wkPay.append(rate[i] * hrs[i])
    i = i + 1
    empNr.append(input("Input employee number or '0' to stop: "))
#calculations using list functions
wkTotal = sum(wkPay)
payHigh = max(wkPay)

wkAvg = float(wkTotal) / len(empNr)
#output summary for pay calculator

print("\n\n Data entry complete " +" \n --------------------------------------")
print("\n Employee Number     Pay Rate     Hours worked     Pay  ")
print("--------------------------------------------------------")
for i in range(len(empNr)):
    print(empNr[i], rate[i], hrs[i], wkPay[i])

print("Summary: ")
print("WEEK TOTAL: ", str(wkTotal))
print("EMPLOYEE HIGH: ", str(empHigh))
print("PAY HIGH: ", str(payHigh))
print("WEEK AVERAGE: ", str(wkAvg))
```

Comment: Apparently either `rate` or `hrs` or `wkPay` has fewer items than `empNr`.

Comment: At least one of `rate`, `hrs`, or `wkPay` is smaller than `empNr`. When you try to print that index, it goes out-of-bounds (tries to access information beyond what the list contains), and python throws an error.

Comment: Note that a good [mre] should be the **shortest possible code** that creates a given problem when run without changes -- all the functionality that isn't related to the issue itself should be factored out when trying to build your question.

Comment: That said, reading your code, it's pretty clear why you have a problem: There exists a `empNr[i]` with the SENTINEL value, whereas there exist no corresponding `rate`, `hrs` or `wkPay` entries. You could fix this by breaking your second loop when you hit that value, or by truncating the `empNr` list at that value to shorten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empNr.append(input("Input employee number or '0' to stop: "))` this line appends `'0'` to `empNr`. But it has no corresponding values for `rate`, `hrs` or `wkPay`. Meaning `rate`, `hrs` or `wkPay` these have one element less than that of `empNr`. A quick fix (but not recommended) would be to loop for `rate` or `hrs` instead of `empNr`. So your code would be:

```py
for i in range(len(rate)):
    print(empNr[i], rate[i], hrs[i], wkPay[i])
```

**A better fix would be:**

```py
i = 0
inp = input("Do you want to add anew record? Y/n: ")
while (inp == "Y"):
    empNr.append(input("Input first employee number: "))
    rate.append(int(input("Input rate: ")))
    hrs.append(int(input("Input hours: ")))
    wkPay.append(rate[i] * hrs[i])
    i = i + 1
    inp = input("Do you want to add anew record? Y/n: ")
```

So while I enter 'Y' I can add new entries and length of each `empNr`, `rate`, `hrs`, `wkPay` would match. If I enter anything other than `Y`, the loop will terminate and the lengths will still remain the same...

Comment: great! thank you, i just tested this and it worked! when i was viewing my professor's code he did something similar to that which had confused me but thanks for clarifying!!

Answer (score -2):

```
SENTINEL = 0
wkTotal = payHigh = wkPay = empHigh = 0 

empNr = []
rate = []
hrs = []
wkPay = []

i = 0
empNr.append(input("Input first employee number: "))
#iteration if 0 is entered it should stop
while (empNr[i] != str(SENTINEL)):
    rate.append(int(input("Input rate: ")))
    hrs.append(int(input("Input hours: ")))
    wkPay.append(rate[i] * hrs[i])
    i = i + 1
    empNr.append(input("Input employee number or '0' to stop: "))
#calculations using list functions
wkTotal = sum(wkPay)
payHigh = max(wkPay)

wkAvg = float(wkTotal) / len(empNr)
#output summary for pay calculator

print("\n\n Data entry complete " +" \n --------------------------------------")
print("\n Employee Number     Pay Rate     Hours worked     Pay  ")
print("--------------------------------------------------------")
for i in range(len(empNr)-1):
    print(empNr[i], rate[i], hrs[i], wkPay[i])

print("Summary: ")
print("WEEK TOTAL: ", str(wkTotal))
print("EMPLOYEE HIGH: ", str(empHigh))
print("PAY HIGH: ", str(payHigh))
print("WEEK AVERAGE: ", str(wkAvg))
```

Please use the above.
Lets say the list had 2 employee details. According to your solution len(empNr) gives 3. The range function will make the for loop iterate for 0,1 and 2. Also one mistake you did was even for the exiting condition when u r accepting the value for 0 you had used the same list which increases the count of the list by 1 to the no. of employees. Hence do a -1 so that it iterates only for the employee count

Comment: Just providing code isn't an answer to the question; it doesn't explain to the OP what their mistake was, or _why_ the new version is better. (Moreover, in a question like this one where the original code wasn't a proper minimal example, copying-and-pasting the whole code into an answer prevents the question from being fixed to have a more minimal example in the future).

Comment: I was just updating the details with proper comments for my solution. Updated now. Thanks